# .NET: what image file types can Image.FromFile() handle?

Tags: .net, image

I use Image.FromFile() to read image files uploaded by a user.  For the 'choose file' dialog box, what file extensions can I allow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From microsoft's documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx

- BMP
- GIF
- JPEG
- PNG
- TIFF

I believe this should be the filter string:

```
Bitmap images|*.bmp|GIF images|*.gif|JPEG images|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jif; *.jfif; *.jfi|PNG images|*.png|TIFF images|*.tiff; *.tif|All files|*.*
```

Note that I allowed for additional valid extensions for JPEG and TIFF images.